# porque no aparece el metodo . union de la clase Query en mi android studio

Tags: java, sql, android, adapter, searchview

tengo la version del     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.1.1' pero aun asi no me aparece

este es el codigo que no me funciona

```
private void buscador(String t) {
    Query nombreQuery = query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Nombre", t).whereLessThan("Nombre", t + "\uf8ff");
    Query marcaQuery = query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Marca", t).whereLessThan("Marca", t + "\uf8ff");
    Query combinedQuery = nombreQuery.orderBy("Nombre").startAt(t).endAt(t + "\uf8ff").union(marcaQuery.orderBy("Marca").startAt(t).endAt(t + "\uf8ff"));
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Productos> firestoreRecyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Productos>().setQuery(combinedQuery, Productos.class).build();
    mAdapter = new adaptadorVerProductos(firestoreRecyclerOptions, this);
    mAdapter.startListening();
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: [La clase `Query`](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com.google.cloud.firestore.Query) no tiene un método `union()`. ¿Lo que necesitas no será encadenar tus `Where`?